# How can I convert String to INT using LARAVEL SQL?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I convert a `String` to an `Int` using Laravel SQL?

My SQL:

```
$playlistArr = ArtistPlaylist::where('artist_uuid', $this->artist_id)
      ->whereBetween('entry_date', [$previousMonthEndDate, $nowDate])
      ->selectRaw('sum(lastSubscriberCount) as lastSubscriberCountSum')
      ->selectRaw('entry_date')
      ->groupBy('entry_date')
      ->orderBy('entry_date')
      ->get();
```

I tried `CAST`, but it didn’t work:

```
$playlistArr = ArtistPlaylist::where('artist_uuid', $this->artist_id)
     ->whereBetween('entry_date', [$previousMonthEndDate, $nowDate])
     ->selectRaw('CAST(sum(lastSubscriberCount) as lastSubscriberCountSum) AS INT')
     ->selectRaw('entry_date')
     ->groupBy('entry_date')
     ->orderBy('entry_date')
     ->get()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a little mistake on your sql.
you need to cast as int first before alias.
change to below will work.

```
$playlistArr = ArtistPlaylist::where('artist_uuid', $this->artist_id)
      ->whereBetween('entry_date', [$previousMonthEndDate, $nowDate])
      ->selectRaw('CAST(sum(lastSubscriberCount) AS INT) as lastSubscriberCountSum')
      ->selectRaw('entry_date')
      ->groupBy('entry_date')
      ->orderBy('entry_date')
      ->get()
```